# How to add the share kit in three20 and also in other views of app in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my project im adding three20.

The project is basically a photo and quiz app.

For the photos client want to display just like three20.He also want to share the pictures through facebook and twitter.So i integrated the sharekit in three20.

In the quiz also all questions is to be shared through facebook.

So when i add the sharekit in three20 and quiz,it is not compiling and some errors are showing.

So there any way to add the sharekit two part of the same project.

Can anyone please tell me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not making any sense. You are just telling us you receive `some` errors

Comment: @SanjeevRao,ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SHKDelicious in /Users/icodingmacmini3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Awesome-gqlhzchmnubhcbetpcfvbiccpdzu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a(SHKDelicious.o) and /Users/icodingmacmini3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Awesome-gqlhzchmnubhcbetpcfvbiccpdzu/Build/Intermediates/Awesome.build/Debug-iphoneos/Awesome.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SHKDelicious.o for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: im sorry for my question.actually i stuck here

Comment: @all so can i use multiple share kit various classes of my project?when i do this some duplication error is showing.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you will have included the same files in the project twice:

The usual suspects are Reachability and ASIHTTP.

Just make sure all your classes are unique.

PS. Your question is indeed stated a little bit cryptic. Please ignore my answer if this answer is besides the point, otherwise I will count this answer toward my psychic badge ;)

Comment: coupe but how can i change the names of files in sharekit.Can you please help me

Comment: You don't need to rename them just delete one of the two